# For loop : count = [0 for i in range(1000)]

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

`count = [0 for i in range(1000)]`

Can anyone explain this line? What do `count` and `0` mean in this code? I'm not sure how this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search **list comprehension**.

- if you want to print all the numbers in this range, put "i" in place of 0:

```py
count = [i for i in range(1000)]
```

- if you add the numbers of this range:

```py
count = sum([i for i in range(1000)])
```

Answer (score 1):

It does simply means the for loop gives '0' output for 1000 times.
and count is a variable and nothing else.

Image about [count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHzPN.jpg).

Comment: count is a variable that I know but I want to know what value store in count. if for loop gives output 0 for 1000 times then why this line needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

for i in range(14, 102): if i % 7 == 2: count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**